# Как выбирать заказы для акаунтов без премиума?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Есть парсер-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get("https://freelance.ru/project/search/pro")
html = bs(r.content, 'html.parser')

for i in html.select(".list-view > .box-shadow"):

    title = i.select('.title')
    
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    print(i.h2['title'])
    print("https://freelance.ru/" + i.a["href"])
```

Сейчас он просто выводит все заказы на сайте. А как мне сделать, чтобы он выводил только те заказы, для которых не нужен премиум аккаунт?

Пытался сделать через метод `find`, чтобы искать блоки в которых есть контейнер с классом `for-business text-success` и если находит, то пропускать его и выводить следующий. Но каждый раз получалось, что скрипт либо выводит ничего или как и раньше выводит все.
Как это исправиьт и реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in html.select(".list-view > .box-shadow"):
    if not i.find('li', class_="for-business"):
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        print(i.h2['title'])
        print("https://freelance.ru/" + i.a["href"])
```